# Uncaught ReferenceError: categoryID is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below throws Uncaught ReferenceError: categoryID is not defined error, what is wrong with it?

```
function selectCategory(obj) {
    var categoryId;
    categoryId=obj.getAttribute("data-category-id");
    if ((document.getElementById("sCategory").value) != categoryID)
    {
        document.getElementById("sCategory").value = categoryID;
        $.fancybox.close(".category-selection-fancybox-popup");
        $.cookie("categoryId", categoryID, { expires : 360 });
        $('.search').submit();
    } else {
        $.fancybox.close(".category-selection-fancybox-popup");            
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `categoryID` is not the same variable as `categoryId`.

Comment: `var categoryId;`, and here `document.getElementById("sCategory").value) != categoryID`, your saying `categoryID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are case sensitive in javascript. In fact [JavaScript is a case-sensitive](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch02_02.htm) language completely. You have declared your variable like `var categoryId;` and in your if condition you are using **Capital D** at end of variable name -> `!= categoryID` and in `$.cookie("categoryId", categoryID` as well.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a [case-sensitive](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch02_02.htm) language. And so the likely cause is that you are referring to `categoryId` as `categoryID` on the following lines;

```
document.getElementById("sCategory").value = categoryID;
$.cookie("categoryId", categoryID, { expires : 360 });
```